# Problema em deixar uma section responsive

Tags: html, css

Estou com problemas para deixar uma section responsive no 100% ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando diminui o zoom da pagina ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```css
.fundoserv
{
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-position: top center;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 width:auto;
 min-height: 800px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 color: #dad9d9;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}
.fundoserv h2
{
height: 100px;
color: #305e78;
font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
 margin-top: 30px;
font-size: 48px;
text-align: center;
}
.fundoserv h1
{
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
margin-top: 100px;
font-size: 80px;
text-align: center;
}

.fundoserv img{
 margin-left: 850px;
 margin-top:-400px;
} // essa parte principalmente.


.ud_active {
 background:#FFFFFF; 
 padding:1% 0 1% 2%;}

dt { 
 transition:all 300ms;
 -webkit-transition:all 300ms;}

dt, dd { 
 
 width: 500px;
 padding:1%; 
 margin-left: 180px;
}
dt { 
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; 
 background: #0B6383; 
 color: #59B4DB; 
 font-size: 25px;
 text-transform:uppercase; 
 border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
 cursor:pointer; 
}
dt:first-child { 
 border-top:none;
}
dt:hover { 
 background:#0FECFF;
}
dd { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
 background:#333; 
 line-height:20px; 
 font-size:14px; 
 word-spacing:3px; 
 color:#999; 
 display:none;
}
```

```html
    <section class="services">
   
        <div class="fundoserv">
   
     <h1>Secure Job</h1>
   <h2>Services</h2>
 <article>
    <dl id="ud_accordion">
      <dt>VITORIAS</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
      <dt>MELHOR DE 10 (MD10)</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
          <dt>ELO BOOSTING</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
      <dt>DUO BOOSTING</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
          <dt>ELO BOOSTING (PREMIUM)</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
      <dt>SECURE BOOSTING(EXCLUSIVE)</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonu</dd>
    </dl>
</article>
 <img src="img/logo.png" alt="faq">
        </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Felipe achei melhor remover minha pergunta, pois ela não respondia completamente a sua pergunta. Te aconselho a ler esse excelente artigo sobre o que é DL/DT/DD e vc vai ver que não é a melhor opção para criar um Menu, ou um Collapse. http://www.maujor.com/blog/2006/04/26/dl-lists/

Comment: eu tinha pego um collapse já pronto, mas você tem algo em relação aquela Light q vc falou?

Comment: Felipe o sistema chama FlexBox tem diversos tutoriais no youtube. São classes CSS para organizar o layout, vai te ajudar muito com a estrutura da página

Comment: opa vou dar uma procurada obrigado! se quiser comentar eu dou voto nele.

Comment: Tranquilo Felipe só leve em consideração que o Zoom do Browser não é a ferramenta ideal para testar se o site é Responsivo. Para isso use a Developer Tool do Chrome. E tente fazer as coisas na mão, as coisas que vemos prontas nem sempre são as melhores opções pro nosso projeto. []´s

Comment: Editei a resposta apena com a parte do Zoom no Browser

Comment: vlw mano vou fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o Browser não costuma dar "zoom" em valores fixos como em PX por exemplo. O ideal pro seu site ficar Responsivo no Zoom do Browser é vc usar todos os valores em % ou Vw/Vh

**OBS:** Apesar disso aconselho usar `@media screen and () {}` para fazer ajustes finos para o zoom no Browser. E pense em usar Medidas em *REM, EM, VW/VH e %, evite PX*.

Comment: Então eu posso refazer toda minha section com utilizando esse testfundo q vc criou como o bg da section e tals e utilizar tudo em % ou em?

Comment: E utilizaria um postion:Relative  naquela div e position absolute em todas outras para ficar dentro dela ou não?

Comment: Felipe pelo que entendi da sua pergunta o seu problema era que ao dar o Zoom com o Browser o Menu Azul ficava pequeno. Mas estou vendo que o seu maior problema seria com o alinhamento dos itens mesmo. Nesse caso seria melhor usar Flexbox e tamanhos em % para não dar problema no Zoom.

Comment: simm também você poderia me mandar um exemplo de flexbox?